# How do I link aem server publish instance with the author instance?

Tags: adobe, aem

I am running 2 aem servers on ubuntu.

```
$ java -jar cq-author-p14502.jar
$ java -jar cq-publish-p14503.jar
```

When I make changes to the author instance and publish, the changes are not showing up in the publish instance. I believe the reason is that the author instance doesn't know the port number where the publish instance is running. How do I tell the author instance where the publish instance is running?

Comment: Did you have edited Replication--> Agents on author --> default agent (or created new replication agent ) that points to your publish server port number.?

Answer (score 5):

Go to miscadmin page [Replication agent author](http://localhost:4502/miscadmin#/etc/replication/agents.author) edit the [default agent publish](http://localhost:4502/etc/replication/agents.author/publish.html) settings Transport tab URI pointing to your publish server. (or create a new publish agent and add the configurations pointing to your publish server)

In your case if your publish server is running on the port number 14503 point it to same with your server name/ipaddress.

Have more information at [Adobe documentation](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-2/deploy/configuring/replication.html#Replication%20(Author%20to%20Publish))

[image: Default publish agent]

[image: Transport uri]